# Why does my LSTM layer keeps throwing errors?

Tags: python, arrays, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, word-embedding

I have a rnn and want to feed in a sentence with a length of 50, and have the output be the same length. (For a chatbot). Does anyone know why this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 5000]
```

keeps appearing? Here is the code:

```
def model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 100, input_length=l))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(LSTM(100))
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
    model.summary()
    return model
model = model()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(padded_x, padded_y, batch_size=128, epochs=100)
```

The shape of both arrays are 5000, 50....5000 sentences with 50 words each. They are already encoded. I first though it was because I was flattening...but this is the error before flattening:

```
ValueError: A target array with shape (5000, 50) was passed for an output of shape (None, 12097) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.
```

##BTW the vocab_size is 12097##

Comment: Why do you call (nearly) everything `model`?

Comment: the function should probably be called `create_model()`. But this isn't a problem. Their code makes sense.

Comment: Anyone know why the error is happening though?

Answer (score 1):

Don't flatten. The size of the output you're expecting is 50, so you need 50 neurons in your last dense layer.

```
def model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 100, input_length=l))
    model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(LSTM(100))
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='softmax')) # 50 here, not 12,097
    model.summary()
    return model
```

Comment: That's not the problem. The error is at the first LSTM node

Comment: did you remove the flatten layer?

Comment: removing the flatten layer starts training...but with this chat bot...doesn't there need to be the entire vocabulary rather than the first 50 words?

Comment: I don't know, you're the expert. You had a problem and I solved it. I've never done a chatbot, so I don't know the proper architecture